# realloc fails with pointer array

Tags: c, memory

I want to create and resize an array of pointers to an arbitrary type. But for some reason, this crashes in the fifth iteration:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int **data = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        printf("begin iteration #%lu...\n", i + 1);
        int *a = malloc(sizeof *a);
        data = realloc(data, ++size);
        data[size - 1] = a;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
begin iteration #1...
begin iteration #2...
begin iteration #3...
begin iteration #4...
begin iteration #5...
realloc(): invalid next size
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I know there are already houndreds of questions regarding `realloc(): invalid next size` and I looked through many of them but I still wasn't able to figure it out. I am pretty sure I am missing something fairly basic here.

Comment: "an array of pointers to an **arbitrary** type" hmmm... then why are you using `int*`

Comment: @4386427 Because this is an example.

Comment: regarding: `int *a = malloc(sizeof *a);`  This results in an unrecoverable memory leak

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not allocating enough space:

```
data = realloc(data, ++size);
```

This is telling `realloc` to allocate `++size` *bytes*, so 1 byte on the first interation, 2 on the second, etc.  This is not enough to hold what you want to store, so you're writing past the end of allocated memory, triggering undefined behavior.

You need to multiply this value by the element size.

```
data = realloc(data, ++size * sizeof *data);
```

Also, you're using the wrong format specifier here:

```
printf("begin iteration #%lu...\n", i + 1);
```

For a `size_t`, the size modifier is `z`:

```
printf("begin iteration #%zu...\n", i + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, at least one problem is that you're allocating `size` bytes instead of elements.

```
data = realloc(data, ++size * sizeof *data);
```